# moment js how to check if endtime is after starttime

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to check if endtime is after start time using the following code. But some reason it is not working.

```
const sTime = moment(startTimeValue,'HH:mm');
const eTime = moment(endTimeValue,'HH:mm');
let x = eTime.isBefore(sTime);
```

I am using angular boostrap ngb-timepicker for start time and end time. want to validate this.

The starrTimeValue is an object with value : {hour: 10, minute: 0, second: 0}

here is my complete code for custom validation to angular bootstrap ngb-timepicker:

```
export function SessionTimesValidator(startTimeControlName: string, endTimeControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } | null => {

        const startTimeControl = formGroup.get(startTimeControlName);
        const endTimeControl = formGroup.get(endTimeControlName)

        const startTimeValue = startTimeControl.value;
        const endTimeValue = endTimeControl.value;

        if (startTimeControl.pristine || endTimeControl.pristine) {
            return null;
        }

        let validationResult = null;

        console.log(moment());

        const sTime = moment(startTimeValue,'HH:mm');
        const eTime = moment(endTimeValue,'HH:mm');
        let x = eTime.isBefore(sTime);

        if(startTimeValue !== null && endTimeValue !== null && 
            ((startTimeValue.hour >= endTimeValue.hour) || (startTimeValue.minute >= endTimeValue.minute))) {
                validationResult =  {'sessiontimes': {value: 'Start Time must be before the End Time'}};
        }
        return validationResult;
    };
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `startTimeValue` and `endTimeValue` are strings? Please show the code how you get the values of them. They might be normal JS objects, at least [it seems so](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples)

Comment: Do you have stackblitz for this?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have stackblitz.